# '02 Hyundai Accent keeps blowing the ignition fusible link

Tags: battery, ignition, hyundai, fuse, accent

My 02 Hyundai accent keeps blowing the ignition fusible link. What could cause this? We just recently replaced the alternator and battery and it was fine when I parked it, then for some reason the car was dead I jumped it. The link has been blowing as soon as I turn the key since.

Comment: Obviously you have a dead short somewhere. I'd run a multi-meter starting at the fusable link and go back from there to see where the short is ... it will probably be self evident very quickly. You could also pull the battery back out and see if you have pinched any wires which would have shorted over the short period of time. Do the same for the alternator.